# Joint Relationships between log normal variables and their Gaussian counter parts

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, copula

I am wondering if two dependent log normal variables $X$ and $Y$ are jointly log-normal would there Gaussian counter parts as in $\ln X$ and $\ln Y$ be jointly normal ? Also what about the converse as in if, $\ln X$ and $\ln Y$ are jointly normal would, $X$ and $Y$ be jointly log-normal or normal ? I am relatively new to probability theory and specially to concept of Copulas. Could copulas be used here to get a formula ?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
:-)

Comment: What do you mean by "jointly log normal"? Specifying this will answer your question.

Comment: @cardinal Well I was under the impression that jointly gaussian means random variables together form a multi-variate gaussian distribution. Similarly i am assuming there is analogous jointly log-normal distribution which refers to a multi-variate log-normal distribution.

Comment: Sure, but what do you mean, precisely, by 'a multivariate log-normal distribution'? Do you just mean "some multivariate distribution with lognormal margins"? Or do you mean something more precise?

Comment: @Glen_b In case of Multivariate Gaussian, it's nice how the marginals end up being Gaussian too. Similarly i was hoping that jointly log-normal would imply that all the marginals are log normal and together they have some multivariate distribution. To be honest i am interested in finding out what this multivariate distribution ought to be or if there are infinite possibilities to choose from what would be the simplest choice so when the logs of the marginals are taken we get Gaussian marginals and a multivariate joint Gaussian density. I look forward to your thoughts.

Comment: With copulas, there are infinite possibilities. The most common is no doubt simply exponentiating the usual multivariate normal. but that choice trivially answers your question. If the aim is to get a multivariate joint Gaussian after taking logs, there's only one solution, which is to exponentiate the thing you want to subsequently take logs of, yielding the obvious solution.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks very much for your help. You may want to promote your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Glen_b What i meant to imply was if you present your comment as an answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With copulas, there are infinite possibilities for multivariate distributions with lognormal margins

The most common multivariate lognormal is no doubt simply exponentiating the usual multivariate normal random variables.

If the aim is to get a multivariate joint Gaussian after taking logs, there's only one solution, which is to exponentiate the thing you want to subsequently take logs of - that is, that most common one.